# Core Plot Bar Graph Y-Axis issues

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to make a bar graph with core plot. I cannot get the y-axis to scale properly or the tick-marks in the correct places. My biggest issue is that if I set:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDEcimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(max_value);
```

And max_value is anything higher then 10 it takes an unreasonable amount of time for the graph to load. For example I need max_value to be around 1000 to show the tops of all the values but when I set it to 1000 it takes over 15 seconds to load the screen. But if I leave it set to 10 my bar graphs take up the entire screen and you cannot see the top.

This is the rest of the part of the code dealing with this. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1000)];
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:_liftOffPlot,_sideLeanPlot,_forwardLeanPlot,_crossLegsPlot,nil]];
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;


axisSet.yAxis.title = @"times completed";
axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = -25.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = nil;

axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
axisSet.yAxis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLocations = nil;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLocations = nil;
axisSet.yAxis.title = @"times completed";
axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = -25.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = nil;

axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"100");
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");

axisSet.yAxis.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(1000)]; 
axisSet.yAxis.gridLinesRange = axisSet.yAxis.visibleRange;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I seem to be finding with most things xcode, it is all about where you put your code. If I have CPTPlotRange:PlotRangeWithLocation:Length before I do my set up it is really slow and buggy. If instead I add it to the end of my code after setting the other values for the axises suddenly there is only a very minor delay. I actually got this code originally from a tutorial and modified it to fit what I needed but I guess the tutorial didn't have the same delay because the length of the data was much lower.

So all I did to fix this problem was put the following code after my axis set up instead of before;

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                            length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1000)];
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray     arrayWithObjects:_liftOffPlot,_sideLeanPlot,_forwardLeanPlot,_crossLegsPlot,nil]];
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

Comment: You must be using Core Plot 1.2. There was a known issue with the labeling code in that release. You found a good work-around. There hasn't been another release, but this problem is fixed in the latest code that you can pull with Mercurial.